# Will lattice deform slow down a preview animation?

Tags: animation, modifiers, rigging

If I use lattice deform along with an armature, will it slow down my animation (speed of preview and render-time) compared same character being animated with just an armature?

Comment: This really depends on you system, and you asked two questions, one of which is primarily opinion based. sooooooo.....

Comment: How much should not be in there. It depends immensely on your scene and machine specs. Better or worse is not a good way to put it. You could post a question asking what uses they are better for though. I'm going to edit your question to make it a little more likely to survive on here.

Comment: Why don't you test it on very-high poly suzanne? Do you want me to do this for you? This site is not full of peasants to do your work, you should test this stuff yourself..on your system you will get best results. You know how to setup all 3 cases (armature, armature with lattice and mesh deform) and you can test the performance also yourself.. you have all the knowledge..